# Is it possible to make separate input fields and after submit join them and save into one database column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formhelper

I have column - `spent time` - it is integer value. I want to make it available to edit for user, but I need to make it user friendly. I mean to make input field for days, for hours etc.

**I will be storing spent time in seconds.**

For example: I eter 2 into hours spent time input field, so I will multiply it by 3600 and add it to other results from inputs.

Is it possible to make it using Rails 3 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if it is suppose 2 days and 3 hours, then how could it be integer storage look like in db?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't telled it right - I'm storing spent time in seconds, so I will mupltyply hours input value on 3600.

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides a function called `date_select` (or, for datetime fields, datetime_select). They takes two parameters–the model instance name, and the model field. Put them in the form_for block, like the other form helpers.

So if you wanted a datetime field, you’d write:

datetime_select("post", "created_on")

Then you can use:

For example, in MySQL you can use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function to return integer times:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) FROM users
```

More from [sources](http://www.railsrocket.com/date-and-time-fields-in-object-forms).

Comment: But you see, my field will be integer in database anyway, because I use it for finding work time - like this - spent_time = Time.now - start_time. So, maybe I will be using date_select, but use some before_filter to convert it to integer.